# Passing $mixpanel_distinct_id to Branch.io in their Web integration

Tags: branch.io

For iOS and Android Branch.io SDK's there's a way to pass the mixpanel_distinct_id.

Mixpanel have a Web integration too. How can this be done when integrating Branch for Web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joon from Branch here. The method setRequestMetadataKey is only available on mobile platforms as conversions such as install, open, reinstall, etc.. only occur in App.